# userID = names[userID] IndexError: list index out of range face recognition OpenCV

Tags: python, opencv, face-recognition, index-error

I am currently building a Real time face recognition system which I intend on testing for my security system at home. I am using the Haar Cascade approach and would like the system to either identify the individuals who have been spotted by the cameras (the peoples name are in the array) or to give us an unknown label.

Code

```
# iniciate id counter
userID = 0

# names related to Userids:
names = ['Mike', 'Yakub', 'Brother C', 'Brother A', 'Robert', 'William']

# Initialize and start realtime video capture
cam = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
cam.set(3, 640)  # set video widht
cam.set(4, 480)  # set video height

# Define min window size to be recognized bv face
minW = 0.1 * cam.get(3)
minH = 0.1 * cam.get(4)

while True:
    ret,img = cam.read()
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    faces = faceCascade.detectMultiScale(
        gray,
        scaleFactor=1.2,
        minNeighbors=5,
        minSize=(int(minW), int(minH)),
    )

    for (x, y, w, h) in faces:

        cv2.rectangle(img, (x, y), (x + w, y + h), (0, 255, 0), 2)

        userID, confidence = recognizer.predict(gray[y:y + h, x:x + w])

        # Check if confidence is less them 80 ==> "0" is perfect match
        if confidence < 80:
            userID = names[userID]
            confidence = "  {0}%".format(round(80 - confidence))
        else:
            userID = "unknown"
            confidence = "  {0}%".format(round(80 - confidence))

        cv2.putText(img, str(userID), (x + 5, y - 5), font, 1, (255, 255, 255), 2)
        cv2.putText(img, str(confidence), (x + 5, y + h - 5), font, 1, (255, 255, 0), 1)

    cv2.imshow('camera', img)

    k = cv2.waitKey(10) & 0xff  # Press 'ESC' for exiting video
    if k == 27:
        break
```

Error message:

```
  userID = names[userID]
IndexError: list index out of range

Process finished with exit code 1
```

I am getting the error message "userID = names[userID] IndexError: list index out of range" even though it should not. My objective is for the box to appear with the name of the person which should be dependent on the UserID array.

Comment: [tour], [ask], [mre]. debug your code. know the values of all involved variables at the time of the exception

Comment: After  'userID, confidence = recognizer.predict(gray[y:y + h, x:x + w])' put print(userID, confidence) to see what you are getting in fact.